# Can I connect a 5 V CAN transceiver to a 3.3 V microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-analysis, can

I have a CAN circuit from another project, and I want to reuse it and connect to my microcontroller, however it is a 5V transceiver and my microcontroller is 3.3 V, is it OK to connect TX and RX directly to my microcontroller?

Microcontroller: http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/03/b4/b2/36/4c/72/49/29/DM00071990.pdf/files/DM00071990.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00071990.pdf

Transceiver: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001667G.pdf

The pins I want to use are pin 93 and pin 163.

Microcontroller output:

[image]

Comment: If and only if the mcu's pins are 5V-tolerant. Check from datasheet.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I checked the I/O structure, they are 5v tolerate I/Os

Comment: You also need to verify that the specified output high voltage of the MCU running on a 3.3v rail comfortably exceeds the input high threshold of the CAN.  Often this is the case, but not *always* - you should actually compare the VOH of the MCU data sheet to the VIH of the CAN data sheet at the intended supply voltage for each.

Comment: Hi @ChrisStratton I am new to this not sure what you mean, but I upload the two datasheets, thanks

Comment: You need to compare the VIH and VOH specs.  For example the VIH of your transceiver is listed at 2 volts, ie, it needs this voltage or higher to *reliably* interpret a "high".  Probably the STM32 output will exceed that on a 3.3v supply, but it would be a good exercise to find the line in the data sheet that says so conclusively.

Comment: @ChrisStratton please see update, you are right it should be fine, thank for your explanation.

Comment: Yes, indeed it looks plausible - though note it shows that if you draw 20 milliamps, the output will sag to about the threshold voltage.  So don't try to also drive any LED's with the same output pins that need to feed the 5v chip.

Comment: @yxing I know that your goal is to re-use your circuit for the CAN transceiver that you listed above, but just FYI, the MCP2562 does the RX/TX level shifting for you. Check it out: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005167C.pdf Figure 1-2, page 6.

Comment: @DanielGiesbrecht but the Vih of MCP2562 is 0.7*Vio which in my case is 2.31v.

Comment: Why not simply use a transceiver suited for the signal voltage levels? There should be pin compatible ones. SN65HVD232 etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### It should indeed work

The Vih on the TXD pin of the CAN transceiver you're using is 2.0V, while the Voh for the STM32 is 2.4V; considering that the STM32 family has 5V tolerant input pins for most of its digital-only I/Os (including the ones you're using assuming we're talking about the LQFP176 package here), you're good on both sides of the deal here.